# some of the pages in pdf coming blank in web browser

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I have a merged pdf that has been merged by some logic. I want to show that pdf in a web browser.

When I test this pdf in my local server, it works fine (it shows all the pages).

But, when hosted on the web it's displaying some pages as blank. I have tested several times, but I've found no solution.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Are the blank pages supposed to have content?  Or are additional blank pages being inserted in between the pages with content?

Comment: no if there are 48 pages in src pdf document and when am going to display it in a web broswer by Respose.BinaryWrite(buffer);where buffer is the byte[] ,But in local it is showing all the 48 pages , but pathetic result is shown in live by first 5 pages missing..

Answer (score 0):

Is the mime type for PDF mapped in IIS on the web server? It should be `application/pdf`
if it's not mapped.